# Multiplayer camera for each player

Tags: unity, c#

I followed [the Official Unity guide for a Multiplayer game](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/handling-non-player-objects?playlist=29690), and now I want a camera for each player.

For this reason, I have set the camera as a child of the player, but it is only showing one player camera for all players. How can I make separate cameras for each player in a multiplayer game?

I have also added this to my child camera but nothing worked

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(NetworkView))]
public class PlayerCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        NetworkView objNetworkView = GetComponent<NetworkView>();
        if (objNetworkView.isMine)
        {
            GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
        }
        else {
            GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to have different cameras running and projecting to different screens, or asking how to get  "split screen" ?

Comment: I want each player own view

Comment: yes.. but is each view designed to be a separate screen, or is each view intended to be displayed on the same screen?

Comment: did you ever play multiplayer game like counter strike on network? how each player looks the own view of the game?

Comment: You should show us what you have tried already, else it is difficult to help

Comment: @realUser404 I have updated the question

Comment: I have, but you would not (and should not) render a camera display *for every player* on the one machine. You would render *one* camera: the camera relevant to the user who is actually playing at that machine. Other player characters are updated from *their* machine, which still only shows them *one* camera: the camera relevant to *their* character.

Comment: i.e. when you say "it only shows one camera for all players", that sounds exactly like what I would expect, playing CS over a network.

Comment: @Gnemlock what is the solution?

Comment: You need to go for a host/server architecture. All the players have their own camera and simply ping the server for what they are allowed to do.

Comment: I've also read before that most games allow the player to walk without contacting the server/host, and every few seconds the server checks to see if their movement was valid. If it wasnt, the server replaces the player back to where they were, you may recognize this in the form of lag in most shooters, where you see players teleporting around at times. It's the server catching up.

Comment: If you have not yet solved the problem with the camera, this resolved: http://www.doofah.com/tutorials/networking/unity-5-network-tutorial-part-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage all players camera by using single camera as @Jhocking mentioned

> In a networked multiplayer game, each player has their own copy of the
>   game running.

So on Local Player Game Copy Side: I make Main camera child to my local player. Here is the code snippet

```
void Start() {


        if (isLocalPlayer)
        {
                GameObject.Find("Main Camera").gameObject.transform.parent = this.transform;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How come you marked YOUR answer as accepted when it is actually jhocking's answer which gave you the solution?

Answer (score 3):

In a networked multiplayer game, each player has their own copy of the game running. So the game only needs one camera, and each player would see their own view.

Comment: each player instantiating with its own camera.